# How to evenly space subcaption - Use table?

Tags: floats, subcaption

I have a single image below and I would like to put a subcaption for each of the image in it. Only for the first row. The way I am doing it is not good because you can see that the subcaption for each image is not aligned correctly.

I was hoping someone could suggest a solution. Below is my code and the resulting figure. To make it easier, it does not need to be in a subcaption.

```
    \begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty,position=top}
    \centering
    \subfloat[$\alpha=0$ \ \ \  $\alpha=1$ \ \ \ \ $\alpha=2$ \ \ \ $\alpha=3$ \ \ \ \ $\alpha=4$ \ \ \ \ $\alpha=5$ \ \ \ \ $\alpha=6$ \ \ \  $\alpha=7$ \ \ \ \ $\alpha=8$ \ \ \ \ $\alpha=9$ \ \ \ $\alpha=10$ \ ]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{latent/latent-interpolation.png} }}
    \\
    \caption{Interpolating between random pairs of latent vectors according to $v = v_1 + (v_2 - v_1) \times \alpha$.}
    \label{fig:interpolate-latent}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

EDIT: So i tried adding a table before the image but I have not been able to reduce to spacing. Adding a negative baseline skips does not work the way i would like it to

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty,position=top}
    \centering
    {\scriptsize
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth { XXXXXXXXXX }
    $x_1$ & $x_2$ & $x_3$ & $x_4$ & $x_5$ & $x_6$ & $x_7$ & $x_8$ & $x_9$ & $x_{10}$
    \end{tabu}
    } \vspace{-2\baselineskip}
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{latent/latent-interpolation.png} }}
    \\
    \caption{Interpolating between random pairs of latent vectors according to $v = v_1 + (v_2 - v_1) \times \alpha$.}
    \label{fig:interpolate-latent}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: do you need real `subcaption`, which can be referenced? or is simple text `a=0` sufficient? centering is simple achievable, if you can broke your image in subimages.

Comment: A simple text a=0 is sufficient. It does not need to be in a subcaption. I would prefer not to break my image into subimages because I have too many more of those images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if all sub-images in your image have equal width and distances between them are also equal, than this might help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{11}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\footnotesize $}X<{$}}}
\alpha=0 & \alpha=1 & \alpha=2 & \alpha=3 & \alpha=4 & \alpha=5 
         & \alpha=6 & \alpha=7 & \alpha=8 & \alpha=9 & \alpha=10    \\
\multicolumn{11}{c}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{latent/latent-interpolation.png} }
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Interpolating between random pairs of latent vectors according to $v = v_1 + (v_2 - v_1) \times \alpha$.}
\label{fig:interpolate-latent}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

since i haven't your image, i emulate it with `demo` option of package `graphicx`. so the final test, if this work for you i had left to you.

[image]

edit: from your comments i conclude, that you actually looking for this:

[image]

which is obtained by:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}% added, i don't now if it is needed
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\subfloat[ sub caption text]{% <--- need to be here
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}% <--- need to be here
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{11}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\footnotesize$}X<{$}}}
\alpha=0 & \alpha=1 & \alpha=2 & \alpha=3 & \alpha=4 & \alpha=5 
         & \alpha=6 & \alpha=7 & \alpha=8 & \alpha=9 & \alpha=10    \\
\multicolumn{11}{c}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{latent/latent-interpolation.png} }
\end{tabularx}}

\subfloat[ sub caption text]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{latent/latent-interpolation.png}}
\caption{Interpolating between random pairs of latent vectors according to $v = v_1 + (v_2 - v_1) \times \alpha$.}
\label{fig:interpolate-latent}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what if i need the sub caption for the image

Comment: i like your solution but i need my subfloat subcaption

Comment: well, first you say, that you don't need subcaptions. honestly, i don't see any reason for this. if you persist, you can replace in first table row with `\subfloat[$\alpha=0$]{}` in each column, however, then probably the text will be broken into two lines due to lack of available space. to make any serious test you need first extend your code sniped to complete small document.

Comment: sorry for not being clear. what i mean was I wanted the alpha=0 and a separate subcaption because I have multiple figures and I wanted a subcaption for them all. But they all have the same alpha labels. I managed to get it to work though by replacing the includegraphics function with the subfloat function. Now i have a subcaption as well. Thank you very much !

Comment: i have a last question. Why can't i use math mode $$ in tabularx. I replaced alpha=0 with $x_0$ and it gave me an error

Comment: columns are already in math mode (see `$` in column definition), so it is sufficient to wrote `x_0`.

Comment: @kong, see edit of my answer. i add example of use `subfloat` as i understood from yours comments.

Comment: @kong, sorry, i edit my answer again. i found some glitches in code and that images was not recent. now all is corrected.