# reduce gap between tabu and subfloat in figure

Tags: floats, subfloats

i have a tabu and a subfloat in a figure function block. how do i reduce the spacing between the tabu and subfloat ? below is my code and figure. i would like a simple solution that does not require me to restructure my code. i want to reduce gap between x1 x2 x3 etc and the subfloat below it

```
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
    \centering
    {\scriptsize
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth { XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX }
    $x_1$ & $x_2$ & $x_3$ & $x_4$ & $x_5$ & $x_6$ & $x_7$ & $x_8$ & $x_9$ & $x_{10}$ & $x_{11}$ & $x_{12}$ & $x_{13}$ & $x_{14}$ & $x_{15}$ & $x_{16}$ & $x_{17}$ & $x_{18}$ & $x_{19}$ & $x_{20}$ \end{tabu}
    } \vspace*{-5mm} %%% HERE %%%%%%
    \subfloat[Ground Truth]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-1-gt.png} }}
    \\ 
    \subfloat[Recurrent Neural Network]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-1-rnn.png} }}
    \\ 
    \subfloat[Variational Recurrent Neural Network]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-1-vrnn.png} }}
    \\ \noindent\rule{15cm}{0.4pt}
    \subfloat[Ground Truth]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-3-gt.png} }}
    \\ 
    \subfloat[Recurrent Neural Network]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-3-rnn.png} }}
    \\ 
    \subfloat[Variational Recurrent Neural Network]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-3-vrnn.png} }}
    \\ \noindent\rule{15cm}{0.4pt}
    \caption{Out of domain runs for (top) 1 shape and (bottom) 3 shapes on the moving shapes dataset. The model received the ground truth as input for the first
20 timesteps.}
    \label{fig:ood-ms}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: you can just insert some negative vertical space with e.g. `\vspace{-1em}` between the two.

Comment: please extend your code sniped to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...} ` and ending by `\end{document}`, that we can see how can we help you. see edit of my answer on your previous question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409959/how-to-evenly-space-subcaption-use-table/409969#409969). there vertical space doesn't seems to be so big.

Answer (score 1):

**edit:** it seems that table introduce additional vertical space between table and sub captions. this can be reduced by adding negative vertical space before end of table:

```
...
\vspace*{-3pt}%
\end{tabu}}
```

modified [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409959/how-to-evenly-space-subcaption-use-table/409969#409969)  to use of `tabu` instead of `tabularx` table:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
\subfloat[ sub caption text]{% <--- had to be here
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}% <--- had to be here
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {*{11}{X[c,$]}}
\alpha=0 & \alpha=1 & \alpha=2 & \alpha=3 & \alpha=4 & \alpha=5 
         & \alpha=6 & \alpha=7 & \alpha=8 & \alpha=9 & \alpha=10    \\
\multicolumn{11}{c}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{latent/latent-interpolation.png} }
\vspace*{-3pt}%
\end{tabu}}

\subfloat[ sub caption text]%
{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{latent/latent-interpolation.png}}
\caption{Interpolating between random pairs of latent vectors according to $v = v_1 + (v_2 - v_1) \times \alpha$.}
\label{fig:interpolate-latent}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

to my opinion spaces between `subfloat`s are appropriate big.